# File Clash in Union Mount Filesystems

Tags: unix, filesystems

I am doing some reading on Union Mount Filesystems from the following source:
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.386.8972&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Here's a snippet from the paper:

> *All filesystem layers except the top one are treated as if they were read-only. If a file residing in a lower layer is opened for reading, a descriptor is returned for that file. If a file residing in a lower layer is opened for writing, the kernel first copies the file to the top layer, then returns a descriptor referencing the copy of the file. The result is that there are two copies of the file: the original unmodified copy in the lower layer, and the modified copy of the file in the upper layer. When the user does a directory listing, any duplicate names in the lower layer are suppressed.*

[image]

---

This seems to leave open the possibility that while an entity (e.g. a container) has a descriptor to the read-only version of the file, another entity, that has RW access, makes changes to a **namesake file** (i.e. having the same name, but from a different layer).  These changes will be behind the first entity’s back, totally unbeknownst to it.  The first entity will not pick up the changes until it is restarted.

Is my understanding correct?

Also, what happens if two entities request RW access, and both entities make changes to files with the same name?

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. What you have proposed is a type of [concurrency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science)) issue. Multi-process and multi-user software often runs into this kind of thing. Databases and Filesystems both implement complicated schemes for controlling these kinds of situations. For filesystems, the answer usually involves [locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking), whereas for databases it's Transactional [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) (a variable and sophisticated locking scheme).

So what your paper is describing is a filesystem that implements "Multiple-read-Single-Write" locking. Many people can open the file for read, but only one person can open it for writing at any given time.

The result of this on the read-users when the source changes is determined by the **application**. The filechanges are (presumably) flushed back to the lower tiers after successful save, so the changes are there for the user, if they look for them. On every OS I've ever used, the program had to specify what kind of access they wanted on a handle (read/readwrite) at the time its opened, and it's those decisions that will drive application behavior.

In general applications will be coded such that they:

- periodically poll the filesystem, notice the change, and ask you if you want to load it
- simply won't notice the change at all, unless the application is closed and reloaded.
- or won't let you open a file if another process has a handle (read or readwrite) open to the file.

So while the Filesystem and the OS handle the locking systems and act as the gatekeepers, its really the applications that are in charge of solving the problem you raise.

As for your second question, it depends. I don't have time to read your paper on this filesystem I've never heard of, but I believe based on what you have quoted, that two files of the same name cannot exist at the top tier (and that that is the whole point of the constraint of top-tier-only writing) preventing the second user from opening the file in Write mode. This is supported by the diagram you quoted, in that there can't be two different files named example.file at /tmp/src/.

The whole point of declaring your access type at handle creation is to check for existing locks and to create your own if allowed, so that currency of the document can be maintained without some kind of merge. Note that just because you have write access to a file, does not mean that opening it for writing is the only way you can open it. Its all up to the application.